# Build a website to show a portfolio of python financial projects?

Tags: javascript, python, css, finance, django

I have developed a portfolio trading strategy using python. I would like to develop a website to show the portfolio trading in real life. Movements in the stock exchange, individual stocks, candlesticks and more. What is the best option to do this in the least possible time?. 
I have no experience in web development only data analytics, but I would like to learn on the go. I know there are frameworks like Django and flask would that be the best option?.

Thanks!,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are in data analysis, the best framework I would suggest is [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/).Dash is a Python framework for building analytical web applications.No JavaScript required.

Django is more opinionated than Flask and Flask is more flexible than Django.

Comment: Thanks you ! thats just what I was looking for!